# How to split date from datetime?

Tags: sql

I am using this query for separating `MIN(INTIME)` and `MAX DateTime(OUTTIME)` from a column. Now after separating `MIN` and `MAX` DateTime, I want to copy the value to another column in which just Date is shown.

```
SELECT 
    EmpID, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN INOUT = 1 THEN Datetime END) AS INtime,
    MAX(CASE WHEN INOUT = 2 THEN Datetime END) AS Outtime
FROM 
    MachineAttendance AS t
GROUP BY 
    EmpID, CONVERT(DATE, Datetime)
```

Please guide

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include the expression in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT EmpID, CONVERT(date, Datetime) as thedate,
       MAX(CASE WHEN INOUT = 1 THEN Datetime END) AS INtime,
       MAX(CASE WHEN INOUT = 2 THEN Datetime END) AS Outtime
FROM MachineAttendance AS t
GROUP BY EmpID, CONVERT(date, Datetime);
```